# To save data, can Core Data provide a fully functional SQLite database that is queryable? Can it do all the SQL searches that it needs to?

Tags: sql, sqlite, core-data

I understand that Core Data is a wrapper of the underlying data structures.  If I'm using Core Data to create a SQLite database, am I able to access a fully featured SQLite database with Core Data?  In other words, am I able to use SQL queries to sort and search my database.  Is the Core Data framework simply an abstraction layer over a SQLite database?

Answer (score 0):

Not simply, no. It isn't just a wrapper and you can't leverage 100% of SQL capability. You search with fetch requests, filter with predicates, sort with descriptors and calculate with KVC and expressions. There is a lot of capability but the design and intention are to abstract away from the underlying storage and provide an object relational data store.

Answer (score 0):

Core Data is not a wrapper or an abstraction layer on SQLite. It's a different API that merely happens to use SQLite internally. Using Core Data while thinking in terms of SQLite is a good way to screw things up. It does quite a lot, and it has **approximate** equivalents to SQL queries, but its API uses different assumptions about how things should work. If you prefer SQLite, use SQLite directly.